# Create and then write to a text file what is printed to the REPL

Tags: java, clojure, functional-programming

How, from a clj file, to take whats is outputted to the REPL by the function "print" and put it all in text file ? 
Is there a way to create a new, empty, text file and put it in the project directory with the other clj files and work on it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by re-binding `*out*`

```
(binding [*out* (clojure.java.io/writer "foo.txt")]
  (print "Hello World"))

(print "This does NOT go to the file") ;; outside the binding macro
```

After this runs, there should be a file named `foo.txt` with "Hello World" in it.

The only caveat is that this re-binding only affects forms evaluated within the `binding` macro.

---

This will re-bind `*out*` to a file writer and not require the use of the `binding` macro.

```
(set! *out* (clojure.java.io/writer "foo.txt"))

(print "foo") ;; written to foo.txt
(print "bar") ;; written to foo.txt
```

I'm not sure if there will be any negative side-effects of re-setting this var. **Use with caution!**

Comment: may you please explain more what should be there is the ns ? 
and the operations to be made ?
The foo file is empty.

Comment: You have to flush in order to get the output into the file, if you don't include a newline. That's why your file appeared empty. Would be best to use `println` for these examples.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly what you are looking for but just for the record you can use [with-out-str](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-out-str) macro.

This evals the output as a `string` that you can store in a file.